# Retornar um objeto vindo de duas ou mais tabelas os campos

Tags: c#, linq, rest, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda

Tenho feito alguns posts sobre rest e lambda, e para dar uma encerrada nesse assunto(espero), tenho uma dúvida. Um colega aqui no site me recomendou que eu criasse uma DTO e trouxesse os dados do banco baseado nessa classe DTO e não direto da Model. Fiz, corrigi alguns bugs com ajuda e resolvi. Bem, acontece que meu serviço, para essa situação, retorna um DTO. Como eu faria isso usando duas ou mais entidades? Assim está meu método hoje:

```
public List<LiberacaoDTO> getAutoriza(int idorcamento)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
                        .Select(lib => new LiberacaoDTO
                        {
                            TipoVenda = lib.TipoVenda,
                            IdOrcamento = lib.IdOrcamento,
                            Juros = lib.Juros != 0 ? lib.Juros : 0,
                            MaxComi = lib.MaxComi,
                            Entrada = lib.Entrada != 0 ? lib.Entrada : 0,
                            Mensagem = lib.Mensagem,
                            Vendedor = lib.Vendedor,
                            Cliente = lib.Cliente,
                            Filial = lib.Filial
                        }).ToList();
            return lista;
        }
```

Essa é minha classe DTO

```
public LiberacaoDTO()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {

                //string userName = null;
                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoDTO, Liberacao>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Juros,
                        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Juros.ToString("C2")
                        ));

                cfg.CreateMap<LiberacaoDTO, Liberacao>()
                .ForMember(e => e.Entrada,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Entrada.ToString("C2")
                ));
            });
        }
        public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
        public byte FlagLiberacao { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdOrcamento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public int IdVendedor { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor { get; set; }
        public int IdFilial { get; set; }
        public string Filial { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float? DataLib { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float? HoraLib { get; set; }
        public int IdCliente { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Juros { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Desconto { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public double Vencimento { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public double Acrescimo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Entrada { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float Prazo { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float TotalLiquido { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float MinTotal { get; set; }
        public string Usuario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public decimal CustoDiario { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public decimal MaxComi { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public decimal ValorComi { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public decimal NovaComi { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
        public string MensagemRet { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public double DataRetorno { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float HoraRetorno { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float TempoPrecesso { get; set; }
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Programa { get; set; }
        public string NomePc { get; set; }
        public string NomeProcedure { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public decimal PercJurosTotal { get; set; }
        public byte FlagCulturaVencida { get; set; }
        public string Cultura { get; set; }
        public int CulturaVcto { get; set; }
        public byte FlagProrrogado { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float ValorProrrogado { get; set; }
        public int DiasAtrazo { get; set; }
        public int IdVendedor2 { get; set; }
        public string Vendedor2 { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public float ComissaoVend2 { get; set; }
        public byte FlagCotacao { get; set; }
        public string TipoVenda1 { get; set; }
        public byte FlagReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
        public string AutorizouReceberAtrazado { get; set; }
    }
```

A questão é que eu preciso incluir uma outra classe, que no meu caso é a `ITENSLIB` e terei de criar uma outra DTO para ela. Isso ok, mas como eu colocaria na Lambda e o que eu retorno. Tentei retornar um `object` e o array ou lista vem vazio. Como incluir tudo isso e retornar um único objeto preenchido com ambas as tabelas na lambda. Abaixo meu serviço que não funcionou. A lista veio vazia:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get")]
        public IEnumerable<object> getLiberacao()
        {
            return liberacao.getAutoriza1(1000012093).AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você vai precisar de um segundo DTO que vai ser uma propriedade do principal. Depois disso basta fazer um join no LINQ para conseguir popular os dados da segunda tabela.

Comment: Isso eu já estou fazendo, mas o problema meu está no que eu retorno. Mas o seu último comentário, parece que pode me esclarecer essa dificuldade que estou tendo.

Answer (score 1):

O conceito da DTO é ser uma classe de transferência, você não necessariamente precisa adicionar na sua DTO apenas as propriedades de uma classe. Seria algo como:

```
var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
    .Include(lib => lib.ITENSLIB)
    .Where(lib => lib.IdOrcamento == idorcamento)
    .Select(lib => new LiberacaoDTO
    {
        TipoVenda = lib.TipoVenda,
        ExemploItemLib = lib.ITENSLIB.Valor
    }).ToList();
return lista;
```

Nesse exemplo eu dou um Include em todos Itenslib relacionando com essa Liberação. Caso o seu Itemlib não tenha relacionamento com Liberação, recomendo que você respeite o principio de responsabilidade única e faça outro método que faça a consulta e outra DTO para ele.